# Basic Probability

Tags: probability, density-function

How to find the conditional/joint probabilities of two variables from their empirically estimated marginal ones and an assumed correlation?

Comment: Are you wondering about the underlying mathematics, or code for how to implement this in practice? (& if the latter, what software do you use, eg R, MATLAB, SAS, etc.)

Comment: You will need to be precise about what you mean by "correlation" and what other assumptions you are making about the problem. (If you need help formulating those, we can assist there, too.) Otherwise, the answer to the question in the generality that it has been asked is: *You can't*.

Comment: Hi gung, thanks for your reply. I need a mathematical formula for the conditional density from the marginal ones and the correlation. I am running simulations on Mathematica with it. I am also curious about the Math, since correlation gives me E(XY) but there are tons of joint densities that would lead to it. So I am a little confused... thanks!

Comment: OK, it actually makes sense that one cannot calculate conditional probabilities explicitly. I use kernel density for the marginal but for the joint is tricky as it is not 1-to-1 correspondence.

Comment: Basically, I estimated the independent densities wit the kernel and used them for a simulation. Now I need a clean-ish way to simulate what would happen if they were not independence, but negatively correlated and vary the correlation coefficient. I am not sure what an appropriate method for this would be.

Answer (score 1):

Iva: The marginal kernel density doesn't really help you with conditional densities. If you are conditioning on the occurrence of a specific event ( which could be values taken on by a related random variable) then you have to separate out the samples for which that event occurred and fit a distribution to that data.  The correlation between X and Y does not give enough information either.  The conditional probability P[Y in A|X in B]  is 
P[Y in A and X in B]/P[X in B].  But there is no specific algebraic manipulation that will convert this into simply a function of P[Y in A] and Cov(X,Y).

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. It is clear to me now! Much appreciated.